# Is it possible to use vi mode in Code::Blocks?

Tags: vim, codeblocks

There is viPlugin in Eclipse, and jvi in NetBeans.My question is if there is a plugin with which I can use vi mode in Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to these; [*VIM + Code::blocks*](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/print-thread/595329) and [*How do I successfully use VIM as an external editor for Code::Blocks?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415326/how-do-i-successfully-use-vim-as-an-external-editor-for-codeblocks) nothing yet of this moment. There is obviously some interest for Vim integration into Code::Blocks but apparently it not enough for gaining enough momentum for someone to start creating a similar solution as for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an old question, but since google leads one here:

cbvike seems to do exactly that

http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,19281.0.html

https://github.com/zmj64351508/cbvike

Comment: cbvike is not a official plugin, and seems to have a lot of problems.